# NavigationView + selector + ripple effect state selected not working

Tags: android, android-5.1.1-lollipop, rippledrawable, android-navigationview

I have searched all things and experimented but not luck with `NavigationView`.

`itemIconTint`, `itemTextColor` and `itemBackground` working with `ripple` effect. but problem is `state selected` not working in `selector drawable`

I have also created `drawable-v21` and put `ripple_navigation_selector.xml`

> My goal is when open drawer again previous selected item should be in
>   yellow color eg. Notifications item

[image]

`NavigationView` inside main_layout.xml

```
  <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:background="@color/black"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/navigation_view_icon_tint_selector"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/navigation_view_text_selector"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer"
    app1:itemBackground="@drawable/ripple_navigation_selector"
     />
```

`ripple_navigation_selector.xml` inside `drawable-v21`

```
<item
    android:id="@android:id/mask"
    android:drawable="@drawable/navigation_selector"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/navigation_selector"/>
```

`navigation_selector.xml` inside `drawable-v21`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:drawable="@color/left_light_yellow" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
<item android:drawable="@color/left_light_yellow" android:state_activated="true"></item>
<item android:drawable="@color/left_light_yellow" android:state_checked="true"></item>
<item android:drawable="@android:color/black"></item>
```

color string named `left_light_yellow`

```
<color name="left_light_yellow">#F6CE20</color>
```

Comment: did you solve this issue?

Comment: works without ripple

Comment: I opened a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37796870/navigationview-ripple-lost-in-support-library-23-1-0-update

Comment: My plus one point for SRT photo

Answer (score 5):

I think you have to make your menu items checkable

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/wishlist"
        android:checkable="true"
        android:title="Wishlist" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have app1?

> ```
>    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
>        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
>        android:layout_width="250dp"
>        android:layout_height="match_parent"
>        android:layout_gravity="end"
>        android:background="@color/black"
>        app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
>        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/navigation_view_icon_tint_selector"
>        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/navigation_view_text_selector"
>        app:menu="@menu/drawer"
>        app1:itemBackground="@drawable/ripple_navigation_selector"
>         />
> ```

I think that if you remove the "1" it should work:

```
       ...
       app:itemBackground="@drawable/ripple_navigation_selector"
        />
```