# NavigationView Ripple Lost In Support Library 23.1.0 Update

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, navigationview, rippledrawable

Using the Design Support Library version `23.0.1`, menu items within the [`NavigationView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html) appear to, by the default, support the [ripple animation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable.html) when selected. However, when upgraded to Design Support Library version `23.1.0` the ripple animation appears to be lost. Is this a bug? Has anyone else noticed this as well and can replicate it? And, better yet, does anyone have a solution?

I first discovered this issue while utilizing the `NavigationView` via Design Support Library version `23.4.0` and noticed a lack of the ripple effect on menu items. However, it wasn't until I followed [this](http://www.android4devs.com/2015/06/navigation-view-material-design-support.html) `NavigationView` tutorial, provided by AndroidForDevs, that I was able to place blame on Design Support Library version `23.1.0`.

To replicate and reproduce the issue, checkout this tutorial's [sample code](https://github.com/AkashBang/NavigationView), which utilizes Design Support Library version `22.2.0`, and bump the version to `23.1.0` in [the app's build.gradle](https://github.com/AkashBang/NavigationView/blob/master/app/build.gradle). You'll then notice the menu items do not ripple when selected. However, if you revert back to version `22.2.0` or `23.0.1` you'll notice the items ripple when selected.

For reference, here is a [link](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html) to the Support Library change log. While it mentions an update allowing for custom views within the `NavigationView` I can't think of why this might have led to the removal of the ripple effect by default as it sounds unrelated. Here is change description word-for-word

> Added support for custom views to the NavigationView class by using
>   the `app:actionLayout` attribute or `MenuItemCompat.setActionView()`
>   method.

Note: This issue is most easily visualized when the drawer is prevented from closing when a menu item is selected. This can be achieved by commenting [this line](https://github.com/AkashBang/NavigationView/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/android4dev/navigationview/MainActivity.java#L54)

Comment: Added to the AOSP Issue Tracker under the Support Library label https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=213077

Comment: Any progress on the bug?

Comment: @SuperThomasLab unfortunately not. The AOSP bug was marked as obsolete but I followed up and indicated I feel that's inaccurate since I'm still seeing the issue in the current version the support library. Any thoughts? I'll be sure to update this post should I find a solution but right now I'll likely let it go

Comment: Haven't found a solution yet, but will try some stuff today. It's strange though, because apps made by Google do show the ripple animation. Can you tag me if you found a solution? I did notice some other apps on Google Play (not by Google) without the animation.

Comment: Yeah it is odd, doesn't make sense that they'd be using a really old version of the support library either. I'll keep you posted if I find anything